# How can I return similar filenames on one line

Tags: python

I'm a bit of a newbie at this so please bare with... I've written a programme for my work to return filenames and duration's so I can easily add them to spreadsheets.  I'd like similar filenames to be returned on the same line so I can copy a whole line of the same files at once.

This is my code so far:

```
import os, wave

def main():

    directory = input("What is the directory? ")
    for file in sorted(os.listdir(directory)):
        if file.endswith(".wav"):
            with wave.open(file, 'rb') as f:
                frames = f.getnframes()
                rate = f.getframerate()
                total_seconds = frames / float(rate)
                minutes = total_seconds / 60
                seconds = total_seconds % 60
                hours = minutes / 60
                minutes = minutes % 60
                duration = '%.2d:%.2d:%.2d' % (hours, minutes, seconds)
                print(file[:-4], duration)

main()
```

It returns:

```
sa-01003-32-su01-pm 00:04:41
sa-01003-32-su02-pm 00:02:20
sa-01003-32-su03-pm 00:09:50
sa-01003-32-su05-pm 00:09:41
sa-01003-32-su06-pm 00:10:15
sa-01003-32-su07-pm 00:09:49
sa-01003-32-su08-pm 00:01:05
sa-01003-33-su01-pm 00:04:04
sa-01003-33-su03-pm 00:02:09
sa-01003-33-su04-pm 00:09:45
sa-01003-33-su05-pm 00:09:39
sa-01003-33-su06-pm 00:10:30
sa-01003-33-su07-pm 00:09:56
sa-01003-33-su08-pm 00:01:05
```

So I'd like for all of the '32' files and durations to be in one line, separated only by spaces, and '33' files and durations on the next line, etc.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To answer your question, I created a dictionary (containing the file names and their corresponding duration) and a list (containing the file names): both of them are returned by the main() function. Next, I created a function that prints the values according to your needs. In short, the function checks if the names in the list have the same prefix (e.g. 'sa-01003-32-): if yes, the names and their corresponding duration (from the dictionary) are printed on the same line separated by a space. If not, a new line is printed. Here is the code:

```
def main():
    directory = input("What is the directory? ")
    dic_file={} # A dictionary that will store the file names and their duration
    list_file=[] # A list of the file names (needs to contain the same names that are present in the dictionary)
    for file in sorted(os.listdir(directory)):
        if file.endswith(".wav"):
            with wave.open(file, 'rb') as f:
                frames = f.getnframes()
                rate = f.getframerate()
                total_seconds = frames / float(rate)
                minutes = total_seconds / 60
                seconds = total_seconds % 60
                hours = minutes / 60
                minutes = minutes % 60
                duration = '%.2d:%.2d:%.2d' % (hours, minutes, seconds)
                list_file.append(file)
                dic_file.setdefault(file,duration)
    return dic_file,list_file  #return the dictionary and the list

def print_value(dic_file,list_file):
    list_file.sort()
    for n,item in enumerate(list_file):
        while True:
            if n<len(list_file)-1:
                if list_file[n+1][:-11]==item[:-11]:
                    print(item,dic_file[item],end=' ')
                else:
                    print(item,dic_file[item]+'\n')
            break
    print(list_file[len(list_file)-1],dic_file[list_file[len(list_file)-1]])

dic_file,list_file=main()
print_value(dic_file,list_file)
```

Comment: I've found that this worked the best for me. Thanks so much for your help, you don't know the hassle you've saved me from!

Answer (score 1):

```
import os, wave

def main():
    directory = input("What is the directory? ")

    current = None
    similar = []

    for file in sorted(os.listdir(directory)):
        if file.endswith(".wav"):
            with wave.open(file, 'rb') as f:
                frames = f.getnframes()
                rate = f.getframerate()
            total_seconds = frames / float(rate)
            minutes = total_seconds / 60
            seconds = total_seconds % 60
            hours = minutes / 60
            minutes = minutes % 60
            duration = '%.2d:%.2d:%.2d' % (hours, minutes, seconds)

            txt = file[:-4] + " " + duration
            value = file.split("-")[3]
            if not current == None:
                if value == current:
                    similar.append(txt)
                else:
                    print(" ".join(similar))
                    similar = []
            else:
                current = value
                similar.append(txt)

main()
```

It is not tested but it should work.

Keep in mind though that that script will only work with file names that contain values separated with dashes.